# Overlay or temporarily replace onscreen keyboard with custom view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

In my Android app, I'd like to slide a custom view up from the bottom of the screen while the keyboard is onscreen, either overlaying the keyboard or temporarily animating it out of the way. Ideally the view would be the same size as the keyboard. The user would briefly reference with the custom view, then tap to dismiss it, bringing back the keyboard.

How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: You can't.  The keyboard is a separate service with its own screen area, you aren't able to draw above it.

Comment: That's too bad. Is there some way to fake it? I don't care if the keyboard is *actually* under there, just that I swap in my view in a way that's not jarring, i.e. use some reasonable animation and preserve the dimensions of the content above it.

Comment: You can use a popup window to overlap it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060579/how-to-draw-view-on-top-of-soft-keyboard-like-whatsapp. As another option I believe you can also attach your view directly to activity window (without using popup window) so it renders above keyboard and overlaps it - saw an app which attaches and draws custom views even on homescreen