# Android move view on top of the keyboard

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout, user-interface

I want to move an edit text on top of the keyboard when the keyboard opens. And when the keyboard closes I want to move the view back to its original position. Something like this [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dSwaI5TaxGaWZE7EE-J3oqdJrxXuMesN/view?usp=sharing).

Here in the video when you tap on the edit text field the keyboard opens and the view translates on top of the keyboard, now when the keyboard closes the edit text comes back to the original position. Also, notice how any view on the background is not moving its place only edit text is moving.

I have done this partially by android:windowSoftInputMode in the activity. but doing so will move the entire activity not that only particular edit text.

So can anyone please guide me with this?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9160259/15298643) you have to manually move the edittext and change your android:windowSoftInputMode so other views don't move

Comment: You should check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060579/how-to-draw-view-on-top-of-soft-keyboard-like-whatsapp/16519421#16519421

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest file inside the selected activist tag add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

and in your EditText add

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Hope this might help